# Logstash wildcard. like "asd*" or Regular expression

Tags: logstash

I want to use `asd *`.

```
if [MSName] == "fm + / *"
```

Then it does not work.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

To check if your string equals `asd *` where `*` is a wildcard, do this:

```
if [fieldname] =~ /^asd.*/ {
   # do stuff
}
```

### Explanation

- `^` means that `asd` should be at the beginning of the line (remove this if it can be anywhere)
- `*` matches 0 or more of the preceding token
- `.` = any character

Logstash supports the following comparison operators:

- equality: `==, !=, <, >, <=, >=`
- regexp: `=~, !~` (checks a pattern on the right against a string value on the left)
- inclusion: `in, not in`

### References

Logstash Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals

RegEx Debugger: https://regexr.com/